# select with subquery takes about 1min in sqlite and < 1s in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sqlite

I already looked up many posts about this problem (subqueries being very slow in sqlite). but I'm not really good with sql and i don't know what i can do.

i have this query:

```
SELECT * FROM data d WHERE d.category = 3 AND 
(SELECT COUNT(id) FROM data_tag WHERE data = d.id AND (tag = 2136 OR tag = 8)) >= 2 
ORDER BY id ASC
```

i have 3 tables 
data,tag and data_tag (n-m of data and tag)
every data has n tags and in this query i search datas by tags (2 tags, both must be in data)

i switched my database from SQL Server to sqlite and besides this query everything works fine.
in SQL Server this one took less then 1 sec to execute and in sqlite it takes about 1min.
plz give me some tips.

Comment: What are your indexes on `data_tag` in SQLite?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT d.* FROM data d
INNER JOIN data_tag ON data_tag.data = d.id AND (tag = 2136 OR tag = 8)
WHERE d.category = 3 
GROUP BY d.id
HAVING COUNT(data_tag.id) >= 2 
ORDER BY id ASC
```

Comment: Sure that `SELECT *` and `GROUP BY d.id` go together?

Comment: Just asking. ;) Not exactly good style (IMO), but if it works.

Comment: +1: Well done, good chap.  Pardon my tardiness, ran out of votes.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
  SELECT d.* 
    FROM DATA d 
    JOIN (SELECT dt.data,
                 COUNT(id) AS num_tags
            FROM DATA_TAG dt
           WHERE dt.tag IN (2136, 8)
        GROUP BY dt.data
          HAVING COUNT(id) >= 2) x ON x.data = d.id
ORDER BY d.id
```

Don't need `ASC` in the ORDER BY - that's the default.

Comment: No need to select `COUNT(id)` since you don't use it anywhere. Also not sure if SQLite can project indexes into temporary tables, a real join might work better.

Comment: @Tomalak: Yeah, realized afterwards when I corrected the column alias.  Shouldn't negatively affect things though

Comment: Yeah, it's one line of code, not more. If indexes work is much more interesting.

Comment: thank you for ur answer, it works fine, but codeholic's is faster
execution time for ur query: 31.25ms